# Dynamic Data To Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-tag-manager, dynamic-data

I'm trying to pull dynamic data (form) to a google sheet.
I can't seem to find the right function.
I'm running this:

```
function name(){
return  $('input[type="text"]').val();
}
```

I tried this:

```
function fullname(){
return $('#form-field-1-1').val();
}
```

No success for now.

I've attached the elements below.

Thank you [https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tt5Gk.png]

Answer (score 0):

Your best choise is to use a Variable "DOM element" and capture it by ID. but if you prefer a custom JS this will do:

```
function(){
    return document.getElementById('form-field-1-1').innerHTML;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, Thanks.
Tried it but it returns 00. Do you know why?

Comment: Nope but u may wanna try with .text instead of .innerHTML